# How do you render a view from a controller in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to render `/list` after updating the Quiz successfully. How do I do that?

```
this.update = function() {
  Quiz.update($scope.quiz, $routeParams.id)
    .success(function() {
      // render /list
    });
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by render /list ? is it so obvious?

Comment: I'm using `ngRouter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the sanest solution would be using routing combined with $location, like this:

```
this.update = function() {
  Quiz.update($scope.quiz, $routeParams.id)
    .success(function() {
      $location.path('/list');
    });
};
```

Of course, it goes without saying that you need to inject $location into your controller, and define the `/list` route (I assume you already have this).

Have a look at this is you want additional functionality: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ngroute or ui-router?

If ngroute

```
$location.path('/list');
```

If ui-router

```
$state.go('stateNameForList');
```